# Defining Equation of 5th Degree Parametric Polynomial

Tags: polynomials, parametric, bezier-curve

I am trying to work with a $5^{th}$ degree polynomial, and I am using Excel to calculate a load of mathematical formulas and equations. I have the form

$$f(t)=a\,(1-t)^5+b\,t(1-t)^4+c\,t^2(1-t)^3+d\,t^3(1-t)^2+e\,t^4(1-t)+f\,t^5$$

The problem is that I am using a complex solver in Excel for solving polynomials, and it can not be in this form. I need to have the equation simplified. I know how to do it by hand, but I am working with hundreds of equations and would rather keep my sanity. It was easy to work with $3^{rd}$ degrees because I had the following:

$$x(t) = a_x t^3 + b_x t^2 + c_x t + x_0 \\
\begin{align}
& \quad x_1 = x_0 + c_x / 3 \\
& \quad x_2 = x_1 + (c_x + b_x) / 3 \\
& \quad x_3 = x_0 + c_x + b_x + a_x \\
\end{align}
$$

$$
y(t) = a_y t^3 + b_y t^2 + c_yt + y_0 \\
\begin{align}
& \quad y_1 = y_0 + c_y / 3 \\
& \quad y_2 = y_1 + (c_y + b_y) / 3 \\
& \quad y_3 = y_0 + c_y + b_y + a_y \\
\end{align}
$$

From there I could complete my own calculations and place in Excel for what I needed. But I am unsure how to do this for a $5^{th}$ degree. Is there a simple formula like the one above for finding $x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5$ and $y_0,y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4,y_5$?

I appreciate any help, it has been 10 years since I took a math class and my mind is already overloaded by learning these higher degrees. So any terminology or hints given please keep that in mind. (I have already searched for hours on Google to no avail) Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=collect%5B+a+(1-t)%5E5%2Bb+t(1-t)%5E4%2Bc+t%5E2(1-t)%5E3%2Bd+t%5E3(1-t)%5E2%2Be+t%5E4(1-t)%2Bf+t%5E5,+t%5D) can do it for you.

Comment: Yes, I use Symbolab Polynomial Equation Calculator, but I have hundreds of equations, and need it in Excel because I have several other equations and calculations based off these polys.

Comment: Sorry, but then I am not sure what your question is. The link I posted shows how W-A can automate it for a given polynomial, which is the same you'd do by hand using the [binomial expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Theorem_statement). If you need to automate that for hundreds of different equations, then that's quite a different matter, and it's not obvious to me how the $x(t),y(t)$ you posted relate to that.

Comment: I am using a Bezier curve, the parametric equation x(t) and y(t). In Excel I can calculate ax, bx and cx and plug them into the x(t), and do the same for ay, by and cy. 

Then I perform other calcs using a poly solve to solve for t when x equals a number. Then I plug that into the y(t) equation to find y. 

The x(t) and y(t) I posted in that form enable me to use the equations in Excel the way I need to based off the control points. 

[The Math Behind the Bézier Curve](http://www.moshplant.com/direct-or/bezier/math.html)

Comment: Sorry again, but you originally posted a $5^{th}$ degree polynomial, then a couple of unrelated $3^{rd}$ degree $x,y$ functions, and now a link about cubic Beziers. It's not clear to me what the question really is, so I'll leave it to someone with a better crystal ball.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a way that works for what I need:

$$\ f(t) = (-a+5b-10c+10d-5e+f)t^5+(5a-20b+30c-20d+5e)t^4+(-10a+30b-30c+10d)t^3+(10a-20b+10c)t^2+(-5a+5b)t+a $$

Where a-f are the control points to the curve. This allows me to work with the formulas in excel the way I need to.